# Enabling login logging in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, login, logging

On a Ubuntu 9.10 system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ionut-laptop 2.6.31-14-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 16 14:04:26 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

the files `/var/log/wtmp` and `/var/log/btmp` are empty:

```
$ ls -la /var/log/?tmp
-rw-rw---- 1 root utmp 0 2010-04-10 16:54 /var/log/btmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 0 2010-04-10 16:54 /var/log/wtmp
```

Because of this, the [last(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/last.1.html) command is not working.

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest your problem is that it's being rotated.  What does `ls -la /var/log/?tmp*` show?

Does your `/etc/logrotate.conf` have entries for wtmp and btmp?